# Why is my data folder empty after I inserted data in mongodb local database?

Tags: mongodb

Following the manual from npm mongodb webpage(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) I created in progect directory and then specified a database directory by typing mongod --dbpath=/data? then I launched this file:
app.js

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myProject';

async function main() {
  // Use connect method to connect to the server
  await client.connect();
  console.log('Connected successfully to server');
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('documents');
  const insertResult = await collection.insertMany([{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }]);
  console.log('Inserted documents =>', insertResult);
  
  // the following code examples can be pasted here...

  return 'done.';
}

main()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
  .finally(() => client.close());
```

and I got success, but folder data is still completely empty. What is wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Databases, do not persist data to disk for each write operation. They flush data to the disk, at periodic intervals, using  concept of checkpoints. Mongodb also follows this concept. Probably when you checked the folder, the data was not flushed at that time

Comment: but after a day it`s still has 0 files

Comment: Ohh ok, does it not even have admin, local databases folder

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you call "dbpath=/data" even being in your directory with this folder created, this command in Windows means that your db will be stored in folder "C:/ProgramFiles/mongodb/data". To specify your progects folder, use full path